# page headings in scrbook and xepersian

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, koma-script, scrpage2, xepersian

I found the page about page numbers in `xepersian`, but the problem seems to be more general. I cannot get the page headings with `scrpage2` in the KomaScript classes to work. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{xepersian}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\lr{\arabic{page}}}{\arabic{page}}}

\usepackage{scrpage2}


\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{latin}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{Test 1}
Text

\newpage

\section{Test 2}

Text 2

\newpage

\section{Test 3}

\end{latin}

\end{document}
```

But this gives me Persian characters in the header.

Comment: Make a bug report in https://github.com/vafa/xepersian/issues but I do not promise updating xepersian package unless there is some donations to the project

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\ohead{\lr{\headmark}}` to your preamble (after loading `scrpage2`) seems to do the trick.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\lr{\arabic{page}}}{\arabic{page}}}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{\lr{\headmark}}

\begin{document}

\begin{latin}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{Test 1}

Text

\newpage

\section{Test 2}

Text 2

\newpage

\section{Test 3}

\end{latin}

\end{document}
```

Output (p. 2):

[image]